# I MESSED UP: I can't install ubuntu as dual boot anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I'm not such an expert user, thanks in advance for your help. Sorry if I can't get quite clear, I'm not a native speaker.

I had a laptop with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual booting, but after an upgrade to 16.04 it got a frozen window (can't remember for sure what it was, something like a custom modification to a certain component, choosing to replace it with a new one from 16.04 or keep the one I had somehow customized).
This somehow invalidated the grub bootloading for this new 16.04

I forgot I could at least try `boot-repair` to fix that, instead I tried to fix by erasing and installing a newer version with a 19.10 live USB.

And so 19.10 worked but then I realized I couldn't dualboot into windows anymore.
So, I erased this new ubuntu partition and tried to fix windows with a System Repair Disk and somehow succeded (a combination of Auto Repair and Restore To A Previous Point).
But Now I can't install a dualboot Ubuntu anymore.

If I boot into a liveUSB, during the Ubuntu Install I can just:

- **either** choose to delete and install ubuntu on the whole disk (or maybe, I guess, on the free unallocated space)
- **or**  choose "Other" and format/resize what it's needed to install a new partition.

I tried the later with not great results, because sometime it prompted me a warning about not having any efi partition.
I realized I might have erased the SYSTEM partition :facepalm: where there should be the EFI bootloader, so I tried to follow [some articles](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html) (or similar to this one) to repair a deleted efi partition, but at the point of `create partition efi` the output says I need to convert to GPT before creating a MSR or EFI.

What does it mean, that I have MBR instead of EFI? By reading this [other article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/windows-mbr-fix.html) it quite seems so, because I got this error

```
5. Reboot and select proper boot device.

When you boot your computer, you may encounter the issue ***reboot and 
select proper boot device*** caused by corrupted or damaged MBR.
```

But I get another issue by following this repair MBR guide at

```
Step 4: Input the following command

    bootrec /fixmbr
    bootrec /fixboot
    bootrec /rebuildbcd

Please hit Enter after each command.
```

I can't get past the `/fixboot` command line because it outputs

```
The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and 
that the volume is not corrupted.
```

Now, since I can atleast boot into Win7 but not install Ubuntu in dual boot, should I tried

- to follow this [Troubleshooting Windows 7 Failure to Boot](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/219533-troubleshooting-windows-7-failure-boot.html) ?
- or to overwrite the whole disk with Ubuntu after a backup of my personal Win7 data?

Comment: Welcome! Since this forum isn't about windows, we can't help you in that regard. *or to overwrite the whole disk with Ubuntu after a backup of my personal Win7 data?*. This seems the simpler solution, if you ask me....

Comment: And you could have in mind also that windows 7 has no more support from microsoft.

Comment: But it seems an issue very much tied to one of my ubuntu install misstep. When trying to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB for just a blink of an eye (before it appears the regular grub menu "Try without install & Install") I can see a single line _Error: file /boot/ not found!_

Comment: Can you try booting the USB in legacy mode? If you boot in EFI mode Ubuntu will try to install in such mode, but your disk has MBR bootloader.

Comment: Ok, I booted in Legay Mode and it finally reappeared the "Install Ubuntu in parallel to Windows" option and I think I can proceed from here without any issue, but I will still hope there is a way to fix whaterever I messed up.


Maybe by creating a 500 MB SYSTEM partition to with both EFI and legacy, but I'm not sure how